# Not redirecting to the login page after login failure in symfony 2.1

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

After login failure, the application does not redirect to the login page.Here is my security.yml configuration:

```
security:
encoders:
    Acme\SecurityBundle\Entity\Users: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER

providers:
    main:
        entity: { class: Acme\SecurityBundle\Entity\Users}

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/login$
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/admin/
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /home

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Here is my controller:

```
class LoginController extends Controller {

/**
 * @Route("/login",name="login")
 */
public function loginAction() {
    //displays login form and renders the login.html.twig
}

/**
 * @Route("/login_check", name="login_check")
 */
public function loginCheckAction() {
    // The security layer will intercept this request
}
```

After login failure I get error as :

```
  The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?
  500 Internal Server Error - LogicException
```

I tried the login section inside the Demo that ships with symfony. I found the same result.
What modification should I have to make in order redirect to login form after login failure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a controller class for the login and logout actions. You just need to specify those routes inside of `routing.yml`, something like:

```
login_path:
  pattern: /login
login_check_path:
  pattern: /admin/login_check
logout_path:
  pattern: /admin/logout
```

These routes are automatically handled by the security component.

In the firewall configuration, your `check_path` should be defined as `/admin/login_check`. The logout path should be `/admin/logout`.